# Linear Algebra eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix. Let $v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$, and let $w$ be and eigenvector of $A^T$ (the transposed of $A$) with corresponding eigenvalue $\alpha$. Show that if $\lambda\neq\alpha$, then $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal (Hint: compute $w^T Av$ in two different ways).

I am kind of lost and don't really know how to solve this.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: What's $Av$? What's $w^T Av$? And so what's $v^T A^T w$?

Answer (score 0):

Just to write them out, $Av=\lambda v$, $A^Tw=\alpha w.$ Note that this means that $(w^TA)^T=\alpha w^T.$ Now compute $w^TAv$ by $(w^TA)v$ first and then $w^T(Av)$ next and compare two expressions..